# Why does CakePHP add New Rows when 'post' is replaced by 'get'?

Tags: php, cakephp, sql-update, http-post

I edit a row on the Post table or add a new row to it from edit() function in PostsController. The function looks like this:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
// Has any form data been POSTed?
if ($this->request->is('post')) { //Replaced 'post' by 'get' in this line

    // If the form data can be validated and saved...
    if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {

        // Set a session flash message and redirect.
        $this->Session->setFlash('Updated the Post!');
        return $this->redirect('/posts');
    }
}

// If no form data, find the post to be edited
// and hand it to the view.
$this->set('post', $this->Post->findById($id));
```

}

I simply replaced 'post' by 'get' to see what would happen and it went on creating new rows without even taking me to the form. I still get the flash message `'Updated the Post!'`, but without taking any form data.

If the code in edit.ctp is required, here it is:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->Create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden','default'=>$post['Post' ['id']));
    echo $this->Form->input('title',array('default'=>$post['Post']['title']));
    echo $this->Form->input('body',array('default'=>$post['Post']['body']));
    echo $this->Form->end('Update');
    ?>
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Edit: Added CakePHP Version

I am using CakePHP 2.4.5

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: I am using CakePHP 2.4.5

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing makes no sense.
Why would you want to switch the "post" by "get" here?
Of course it will then generate new rows, as you effectively trigger a save on each page load (GET).
Don't do that.
The code you had there was just fine - IF you also took PUT into consideration.
For edit forms, it is not a post, but:

```
if ($this->request->is('put')) {}
```

PS: If you want to make sure it always works for both add/edit, use

```
 if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put')) {}
```

But NEVER replace it with "get".

Comment: Thanks Mark. 'post' was working just fine. I just started learning CakePHP, and was curious to know what would happen when 'post' would be replaced by 'get'. And the result had me thinking why that happened.